# Supervisor / Administrator Mode

Tags: operating-system

What are the assembly commands that can be executed only with administrator or supervisor authorization? (kernel 00)

Comment: What's the processor? What have you done yourself to answer the question?

Comment: Intel pentium. i looked for it all over the internet.

Comment: http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

Comment: thanks but it doesn't help me.

Comment: How can that not help you?  Volume 2 contains a list of all IA-32 instructions and explicitly states which are privileged.

Answer (score 0):

well...if I had to guess off the top of my head, I would say

```
halt
```

or something comparable to it on your architecture.

This halts the entire system...normally used during shutdown.